# Cannot enable Android Lint rules via Gradle

Tags: android, lint

I'm trying to enable disabled-by-default rules in Android Lint. I've added Android Lint to my Gradle config like this:

```
android {

    // …other config…

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
    }
}
```

When I run `./gradlew lint` I get a HTML report generated that mentions: "Disabled Checks (28)" and gives me the names and descriptions of the rules disabled.

The [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#config) say that I can pass an "enable" option, with a set of strings. I've tried to enable *all* disabled rules as follows:

```
lintOptions {
    enable 'AppLinksAutoVerifyError', 'AppLinksAutoVerifyWarning', 'BackButton', 'DalvikOverride', 'DuplicateStrings', 'EasterEgg', 'FieldGetter', 'GoogleAppIndexingApiWarning', 'IconExpectedSize', 'ImplicitSamInstance', 'KotlinPropertyAccess', 'LambdaLast', 'LockedOrientationActivity', 'LogConditional', 'MangledCRLF', 'MinSdkTooLow', 'MissingRegistered', 'NoHardKeywords', 'NonResizeableActivity', 'RequiredSize', 'SourceLockedOrientationActivity', 'StopShip', 'SyntheticAccessor', 'UnknownNullness', 'UnpackedNativeCode', 'UnsupportedChromeOsCameraSystemFeature', 'ValidActionsXml', 'WrongThreadInterprocedural'
    abortOnError true
}
```

When rerunning `./gradlew lint` it now says "Disabled checks (23)" — I can see that checks such as `StopShip` and `DuplicateStrings` are now enabled, but many others — e.g. `AppLinksAutoVerifyError`, `AppLinksAutoVerifyWarning`, `BackButton`, `DalvikOverride`, `EasterEgg`, etc —  are 'stuck' on disabled.

How can I enable these rules? Is there a maximum number of rules that can be ran at one time?

Comment: reference https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/LintOptions

Comment: @RajaNagendraKumar thanks, but the linked page mentions the same `enable` option that I'm already using above? (if you meant that I should do something different, if you could expand on your comment or write an answer to explain that, that'd be great)